# Comma splices correction

Tags: grammaticality, conjunctions, semicolons, comma-splices

Which one is correct?

In the Middle Age a lord’s intricate wall hangings were more than mere tapestries

1. ; they were
2. and were

a measure of his consequence and wealth.

Comment: There is an explanation rather than a general addition of information, so 'and' is inappropriate. I'd far prefer a dash to a semicolon also.

Comment: I too dislike the semicolon. The second part does not have the same status as the first so the semicolon is not appropriate. Contrary to Edwin A, I have only small objection to the "and". The second part is not much of an an explanation of the first - it also has some quality of an independent addition, just as it would have had in saying that the tapestries helped insulate the dwelling, or educated the lord's children about the depicted historical events.